# Inheritance Generic Invariance C#4

Tags: c#-4.0, generics, inheritance, instance, variance

I've been searching why this generic contruction doesn't compile

I get:
Cannot implicitly convert type 'WpfApplication1.CowDao' to 'WpfApplication1.Dao'

```
public abstract class Animal { }

public class Dog : Animal { }

public class Cow : Animal { }

public abstract class Dao<T> where T : Animal 
{
    public void Insert(T t);
}

public class DogDao : Dao<Dog> { }

public class CowDao : Dao<Cow> { }

public class Main
{
    public Main()
    { 
        Dao<Animal> dao = null;

        if (true) dao = new DogDao();
        else dao = new CowDao();
    }
}
```

I just want to get to my goal --> making a 'neutral' instance
I think that my construction has to change, but i don't know how

I'm using .NET Framework 4

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change your Inheritance for your Dao layers as

```
public class DogDao : Dao<Animal> { }

public class CowDao : Dao<Animal> { }
```

Edit:

```
 public abstract class Dao<T> where T : Animal
    {
        public virtual void Insert(T t)
        {

        }

        protected void ExecuteQuery(string quer)
        {

        }
    }

    public class DogDao : Dao<Dog>
    {
        public override void Insert(Dog t)
        {
            string insert = "INSERT INTO DOG ...";

            base.ExecuteQuery(insert);
        }
    }

    public class CowDao : Dao<Cow>
    {
        public override void Insert(Cow t)
        {
            string insert = "INSERT INTO COW ...";

            base.ExecuteQuery(insert);
        }

    }
```

Comment: But then my generic structure isn't usefull, and i need it because of the specific methods in cow and dog

Comment: You dou have Dog & CowDaos, why do you need specific methods in your base dao? Just implement them in your specific daos

Comment: Because of the different sql-query

Comment: I understand that you have differnt queries per type, but why do you implement those in your base dao? They dont belong there. Define a virtual method in your base dao and implement it specific in your derived dao

Comment: no not in my base dao, but in cowdao and dogdao. And the logics of what to do with de query --> base dao

Comment: See edit of my answer, if this does match your requirements, maybe try rephrasing / setting up a new question

Comment: Yes, and now i want to make a variable where I can put an instance of CowDao or DogDao in. Then I would just have to say 'instanceOfDao'.Insert(o)

Answer (score 0):

Generics from a derived does not inherit from Generic from a base class so you may not cast one to another. Instead, write an extension method ToGenericParent that converts like that:

```
public static Generic<Parent> ToGenericParent(this Generic<Derived> derived)
        {
            return new Generic<Parent>() { Value = derived.Value };
        }
```

Comment: And how do I have to implement it?